# How do you check if a serial port is open in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

How does one check if a serial port is already open in Linux using Posix/C functions? I want to check the status of the serial port to check if the serial port is open or not.

I would like to know what methods work for:

1. Checking the **file descriptor** to see if the serial port is open and
2. Checking the **serial port file name** to see if the the serial port is open which in the example below is "/dev/ttyUSB0"

--

```
// This code is for example purposes only

int open_port()
{
  int fd;

  fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
  if (fd < 0)
  {
    perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyf1 - ");
  }

  return fd;
}
```

I imagine there is a "standard" way of doing this, and that is what I am trying to get to.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980725/locking-linux-serial-port

Comment: It looks similar, but does not provide the solution as this is how to check if the port is open. It just provides a way to exclusively lock it.

Comment: @Xofo: Applications should exclusively lock the port (via the TIOCEXCL ioctl and/or flock()/fcntl() on the open file descriptor) to avoid others being able to open the device and mess with its settings, input, or output. *That is the standard solution*. To check if the port is in use, you simply try to open it. If you can open it, it is not used by any other application. All other solutions are wrong, because they contain race conditions, or are otherwise unreliable or conflict with e.g. device discovery daemons.

Comment: @NominalAnimal - Thank you for your comment. Your comment is a solution. You are saying that your solution is a "best practices" solution. What are the other solutions? I think they merit some discussion. You say TIOCEXCL ioctl AND/OR flock()/fcntl() - Is it safe one or both functions?

Comment: Duplicate of [What is the best practice for locking serial ports and other devices in Linux? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316722/what-is-the-best-practice-for-locking-serial-ports-and-other-devices-in-linux)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two aspects to the stated question, which really require two different solutions:

1. An application or service daemon using a serial port should exclude other processes from using the port concurrently.

   There are two ways of doing this: exclusive mode, and an advisory lock. An application can choose to do one, or both.

   - After opening the device, use [`ioctl(fd, TIOCEXCL)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty_ioctl.4.html) to put the serial port into exclusive mode. Until the descriptor is closed, or the process issues `ioctl(fd, TIOCNXCL)`, any attempt to open the device will fail with `EBUSY` error code.
   - After opening the device, use [`flock(fd, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html) to try and place an exclusive advisory lock on the open device. Other processes can still open the device normally, and even read and write to it, but trying to place an advisory flock lock on it will fail with `EWOULDBLOCK` (or block until unlocked or closed if placed without `LOCK_NB`).

   The difference between the above two approaches is that the latter is co-operative, allowing other processes to open the device; while the former disallows further opens.

   The reason to use both, is to detect if another process has already opened the device without putting it into exclusive mode, but has hopefully set the advisory lock. In that case, the open() and ioctl() both succeed, but the flock() fails.

   (We can use the second aspect of this question discussed below — after having opened the device, set it to exclusive mode, and even obtained the exclusive lock on it —, to detect if other processes have the device open but not exclusive or locked. Personally, I wouldn't bother; I do expect users to only use sane applications on their systems. If they really did that, I'd expect them to have a reason for it, so I'd prefer to allow that oddball scenario. It definitely should not occur with standard utilities.)
2. An application or daemon can use `lsof` (from the lsof package) to examine if any process has the specified file or device open.

   The idea is to run the equivalent of `LANG=C LC_ALL=C lsof -F -p DEVICE` with root privileges. The output will contain zero or more lines. The lines beginning with `p` (and immediately followed with the PID and a newline `\n`) specify the processes that have `DEVICE` open. (Each such line is followed by one or more lines starting with `f`, describing which descriptor in that process refer to the device.)

   If the application or daemon does not have root privileges, a helper program that is installed setuid root is needed. It is supplied with one or more device names. The helper program verifies each one is a character device using `stat()` and `S_IFCHR(st_mode)` (to avoid the helper being used in security exploits); and if they are, executes the above-mentioned command. In Linux, such helpers are usually installed in `/usr/lib/APPLICATION/`, where `APPLICATION` is the name of the application or daemon.

   The application or daemon itself can execute the helper via [`popen("/path/to/helper 2>/dev/null", "r")`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html), and read the input using for example `fscanf()`. (Remember to use [`pclose()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pclose.3.html) to obtain the status, and use e.g. [`(WIFEXITED(status) && !WEXITSTATUS(status))`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) to verify the command was successful.

   Note that the helper program approach allows easier portability to other POSIXy systems from Linux, by simply replacing the helper program with one appropriate to the new system. Even if it is not installed as setuid root, it gives system maintainers an easy hook to modify the behaviour of the application or service, if such need arises.  I personally warmly recommend the helper approach.

Answer (score 1):

Though not completely related, in that this answer is specifically about `lsof`, this is relevant as it provides clues how to use a similar sequence of kernel calls as `lsof`.

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49687230/1364242) containing `LANG=C LC_ALL=C lsof -F -p DEVICE` did not work for me as `-p` means process id, and when `lsof` queries a **char special** (i.e. tty) device it seems to block for a long time or hang indefinately.

After a read of the [lsof man](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) page:

```markdown
-O
    This option directs lsof to bypass the strategy it uses to avoid being blocked by some kernel operations - i.e., doing them in forked child processes. See the BLOCKS AND TIMEOUTS and AVOIDING KERNEL BLOCKS sections for more information on kernel operations that may block lsof. 
While use of this option will reduce
    lsof startup overhead, it may also cause lsof to hang when the kernel doesn't respond to a function. Use this option cautiously.
```

I tried `-O` and it immediately worked.

So, despite my reading of the man page indicating otherswise, I had success with:

```bash
lsof -t -S 2 -O /dev/ttyS0
```

-t   = Terse output (no minimal detail, no headers)
-S 2 = Reduce 15s timeout on blocking kernel calls to 2s
-O  = Ask lsof to avoid certain kernel calls that might block

Comment: Thank you for this helpful contribution.